# Join on column with 2 identifiers

Tags: sql, join

i have the following problem:

My table "SO_TABLE" have a "SO_ID" column that is the primary key.

I need to join on "TECH_TABLE" for more informations, but, sometimes, the "TECH_TABLE" has 2 "SO_ID" on the same column, like this: 
SO_TABLE:

```
+------+--+
| SO_ID   |
+------+--+
|  123 |  |
|  456 |  |
|  789 |  |
+------+--+
```

TECH_TABLE:

```
+-------------+--+
|    SO_ID    |  |
+-------------+--+
| D:123 F:456 |  |
| 789         |  |
+-------------+--+
```

I need to go on SO_TABLE and, for each row '123' and '456' catch the values on tech_table for the first row. 


But how can i join on columns like this, with 2 identifiers on the same row/column?

See in sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38269b/2/0

I need to reference the first line on TECH_TABLE on both first and second line of my SO_TABLE basead on SO_ID

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: What are the types of these SO_ID columns?

Comment: SO_ID are string columns

Comment: Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38269b/2/0

Comment: I need to reference the first line on TECH_TABLE on both first and second line of my SO_TABLE basead on SO_ID